# MVC Controller - Inject 2 repositories in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm trying to inject a second repository into my asp.net mvc 3 controller. And I cant get it to work, not sure where to "add another" using Ninject.

I have a void function in global.asa.cs

```
kernel.Bind<INewsRepository>().To<NewsRepository>();
```

And in my controller I have:

```
private INewsRepository _newsRepository;
private IContentRepository _contentRepository;

public NewsController(INewsRepository newsRepository, IContentRepository contentRepository)
{
    this._newsRepository = newsRepository;
    this._contentRepository = contentRepository;
}
```

How can I register IContentRepository for the NewsController as well?

Comment: You are not declaring dependencies for just `NewsController`.  You are declaring that any class that depends on `INewsRepository` use the specified concrete class.  Do the same for `IContentRepository` and when ninject needs to create a `NewsController` it will recognize there is more than one dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use autofac instead of Ninject but the basics stay the same.

If you got your first dependency injection working then you should be able to bind others as well. You just have to add a new binding in Application_Start() in your Global.asax.

So under your first binding do this as well:

```
kernel.Bind<IContentRepository>().To<ContentRepository>();
```

You can have as many bindings as you like.

Comment: that was the answer, and I had it all along.... I just didnt have the change compiled :S

Answer (score 2):

First off it's a good practice to move the bootstrapping of your application into a separate location.  This keeps your Global.asax clean.

You should also be using convention based registration.  It will end up saving you lots of time for the bindings you don't need to customize.

So for you I'd probably suggest the following

```
public static class Bootstrapper()
{
   public static void Bootstrap()
   {
      kernel.Scan( k =>  
      {  
         k.FromAssemblyContaining<INewsRepository>();  
         k.BindWithDefaultConventions();  
       });  
   }
}
```

And in your Global.asax you add this..

```
Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
```

Then I would suggest you spend some time on Google reading about ninject conventions.